# UV9RTP Slow transmit to receive

Tags: baofeng

When I transmit the there is a delay in the receiving. When I let off of the mic it still transmits for a few milli-seconds. The transfer to receive is not instantaneous.

Which setting controls this ?

de  W3ASW

Comment: Hello Michael, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 2):

If the UV-9RTP is like the UV-5R, then that sounds like either the squelch tail elimination (STE) feature, which is menu item 35 in a UV-5R, or the repeater squelch tail elimination (RP-STE), which is menu item 36.

When STE is enabled, then the radio transmits a 55 Hz tone (FM modulated as usual) for a moment after the PTT button is let go.  Other Baofeng radios will mute the receiver when they hear the 55 Hz tone in the received audio.  (This only works in a simplex communication with another Baofeng.  Radio models by other manufacturers don't mute the receiver for a 55 Hz tone, and a repeater will ignore the tone and filter it out of the audio before repeating it.)

For a radio with RP-STE enabled, it mutes its own receiver for a moment after PTT is let go, so that the radio won't pick up the repeater's squelch tail.  The radio doesn't actually transmit after PTT is let go, but you might think that it's still transmitting, because the receiver doesn't operate for a moment.